# Django & Python AttributeError: 'Retailer' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my test file:

```
class TestMakeSoup(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['deals_test_data.json']

    def test_string_is_valid(self):
        s = Retailer.objects.get(pk=1)
        with open('/home/danny/PycharmProjects/askarby/deals/tests/BestBuyTest.html', 'r') as myfile:
            text = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    self.assertTrue(s.make_soup(text))
```

In the file it's testing:

```
class retailer():
    '''
    Retail site, drawn from database queryset object
    '''
    def __init__(self,r_object):
        '''
        Initializes retailer variables
        obj -> nonetype

        Precondition: r_object.currency == 3
        Precondition: r_object.name != None
        '''
        assert len(r_object.currency) == 3, "{} must be a three-letter string (eg 'USD').".format(r_object.currency)
        assert r_object.name != None, "Name must exist."
        assert r_object.deal_container_css != None, "Title css must exist."
        assert r_object.title_css != None, "Title css must exist."
        assert r_object.price_css != None, "Price css must exist."
        self.name = r_object.name
        self.base_url = r_object.base_url
        self.currency = r_object.currency
        #dict containing css lookup values for various fields
        self.css = {}
        self.css['container'] = self.extract_css(r_object.deal_container_css)
        self.css['title'] = self.extract_css(r_object.title_css)
        self.css['product_model'] = self.extract_css(r_object.product_model_css)
        self.css['price'] = self.extract_css(r_object.price_css)
        self.css['old_price'] = self.extract_css(r_object.old_price_css)
        self.css['brand'] = self.extract_css(r_object.brand_css)
        self.css['image'] = self.extract_css(r_object.image_css)
        self.css['description'] = self.extract_css(r_object.description_css)
        self.css['exclude'] = self.extract_css(r_object.exclude_css)
        self.css['shipping'] = self.extract_css(r_object.shipping_css)

        #dict containing associated clearance urls for retailer
        self.clearance_urls = self.get_clearance_urls()

        #dict to house final list of deals
        self.deals = {}


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def make_soup(self, text):
        assert isinstance(text,str), "text must be string."
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
        if soup:
            return soup
        return False
```

The `Retailer` call refers to the `Retailer` model in my deals app.
I get this error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danny/PycharmProjects/askarby/deals/tests/test_deals.py", line 101, in test_string_is_valid
    self.assertTrue(s.make_soup(text))
AttributeError: 'Retailer' object has no attribute 'make_soup'
```

Why isn't `make_soup` running as a method?

Comment: check the classname, is `make_soup` actually exists in `Retailer` class?

Comment: Yes it does. The problem was that I wasn't actually creating the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retailer class takes an object retrieved from the database. I retrieved the object from the database but didn't create a class with it.

```
def test_makesoup(self):
    z = Retailer.objects.get(pk=1)
    s = dealscan.retailer(z)
    with open('/home/danny/PycharmProjects/askarby/deals/tests/BestBuyTest.html', 'r') as myfile:
        text = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    self.assertTrue(s.make_soup(text))
```

solves it.